# EC2 domain name ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have bought a domain name from GoDaddy and would like to host it on an EC2 instance. I have created the instance and have installed apache. I have added an index.php with phpinfo(); and it is showing correctly when I access the public IP on browser. Now I would like to point my domain name to this instance. For this I have added an `A RECORD` at Godaddy DNS configuration. But when I access the doamin, it is showing

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

message in the broswer. Is there any additional settings I need to do ?

Comment: What you described sounds fine and should be enough. Can you confirm, for example using https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/, that your dns name resolves to the correct public IP address?

Comment: Also, is that perhaps `.dev` domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is what it is needed. SO if it is not working then then you have to check everything again :
- check (for example with ping) if the domain is in fact resolving to correct IP address (from your computer and from instance for example to use different DNS servers). You can also use `host` command (for example `host www.mydomain.com 8.8.8.8` - it will use google's dns (8.8.8.8) as the source of truth
- check if Security Group in aws allows inbound traffic (that's probably true as you can reach the instance directly)
- try to connect from different network (again this should not be problem as IP is reachable using IP).

you can also post the domain name and requested Ip so we can check this for you ;)